# Pandas appending to series

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I am trying to write some code to scrape a website for a list of links which I will then do something else with after. I found some code [here](https://github.com/jabbalaci/Bash-Utils/blob/master/get_links.py) that I am trying to adapt so that instead of printing the list it adds it to a series. The code I have is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin
user_agent = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0'}

linksList = pd.Series()

def process(url):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=user_agent)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")

    for tag in soup.findAll('a', href=True):
        tag['href'] = urljoin(url, tag['href'])
        linksList.append(tag['href'])
```

When I pass a URL I get the following error

```
cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object
```

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.append()` method of a `Series` object](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.append.html) expects an another `Series` object as an argument. In other words, it is used to concatenate `Series` together.

In your case, you can just collect the `href` values into a list and initialize a `Series`:

```
def process(url):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=user_agent)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")

    return [urljoin(url, tag['href']) for tag in soup.select('a[href]')]:

links_list = pd.Series(process())
```

Comment: Thanks easy when you know how